# Error Executing SSIS Web Service task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bids

I am trying to execute SSIS Web service task and i get the following error when I execute it:

> [Web Service Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error
>   message:
>   "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException:
>   Could not execute the Web method.     The error is: Could not create
>   an object of the type ProxyNamespace.UnallocatedLaborHours[]&. Check
>   whether the default constructor exists..    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebMethodInvokerProxy.InvokeMethod(DTSWebMethodInfo
>   methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTaskUtil.Invoke(DTSWebMethodInfo
>   methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection, VariableDispenser
>   taskVariableDispenser)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTask.executeThread()".

I have configured the HTTP Connection Manager correctly using a proxy. I also clicked 'Test Connection' and I get a message that it passed.

Input to my webservice is a string element and I made sure i am passing the string as input.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: hello friend, have you found a solution? Now I meet this error too.

Comment: Same here, any comments?